# Setting a checkbox value within a model list (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have the following in MVC:

Area of Impact:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ImpactAreas.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].ImpactAreaID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].Description)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].IsActive)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].ConcurrencyDateTime)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].InsertedDateTime)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].Checked)
    }

    @foreach (var area in Model.ImpactAreas)
    {
        CurrentImpactArea = area.Name;
        string myImpactAreaName = "ImpactArea" + CurrentImpactArea;
        <div class="columns large-2 medium-3 small-4">
         <input type="checkbox" @area.Checked name="@myImpactAreaName" value="@area.ImpactAreaID" @(area.ImpactAreaID == Model.ImpactAreaID ? " checked='checked'" : "") /><label title="@area.Description" for="ImpactAreaID">@area.Name</label>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I am trying to get the checkbox to set the value in the list item with the checkbox checked status (true/false) in the impact area object:

```
public bool Checked {  get; set; }
```

however in my main object, I have a list of the above object

Any help?

Comment: can you give us the model you are passing to the view?

Comment: Have you checked the HTML generated in the browser? Also you could just assign the boolean expression to the checked attribute and razor would handle it properly.

Comment: Hi, Yes it was a one to one relationship at first so I used radiobuttons and stored the value ID of the selected item in the model. But now changed to a one to many relationship. Stephen Muecke, your solution helped me steer into the right direction, please post it as a answer so I can mark it as correct. Still new to MVC, don't have a problem with the html part, just still figuring razor out

Answer (score 1):

You first `for` loop is correctly generating the form controls for your model, but you have hidden input for the `Checked` property which renders the initial value of the property, and its that value which will be bound when you submit the form (your just sending back the original data you sent to the view.

Your second `foreach` loop is generating form controls which have no relationship to your model and will not bind to your model (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for more details of why using a `foreach` loop will not work)

In addition, your degrading performance by rendering all those hidden inputs and sending them all back again unchanged. Use a view model containing only 2 properties - `ImpactAreaID` and `Checked` and when you submit the form, get the records from the database based on the ID property, update the records `Checked` property based on the view model and save it (refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)).

Your view code just needs to be

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ImpactAreas.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].ImpactAreaID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].Checked)
    // assumes you want the Name value to be used as the label for the checkbox
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImpactAreas[i].Checked, Model.ImpactAreas[i].Name)
}
```

Comment: you are always best in providing answer and explaining them @Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@Model.name" id="@Model.name" @(Model.Checked ? "checked" : "") />
```